# Open text file on a FTP account with PHP

Tags: php, csv, ftp, fopen

I'm trying to read a CSV file on a FTP account but the same code that I use for other accounts is not working anymore.

This new FTP account, when I connect to it using FileZilla, for example, an window saying things about a certificate is shown. I have to agree, than I can access the FTP files normally through the program. I imagine that this certificate thing is the cause of my problem.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
$filename = "ftp://$user:$pass@$host/filename.csv";

 $fh = fopen($filename, "r");

 while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh);
    var_dump($line);
 }
 fclose($fh);
```

Is there a way to change my code to consider the requirements of this FTP account that involves a certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently don't have a server to test but to allow invalid certificates (I assume that's the question) when using stream wrappers you need to create a proper [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) and pass it as [fopen()](http://php.net/fopen)'s 4th argument. The context options that apply are [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ftp.php) and [SSL](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php). You probably want to set [verify_peer](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.verify-peer) to `false`.

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer'       => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ]
]);
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r', false, $context);
```

Comment: Can you help me giving me a simple example? Reading the documentation dindn't help that much.

Comment: Still not able to connect.. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Have you verified that you can actually see the error messages if any? A simple way is to make an intentional mistake, such as typing an invalid host.

Comment: I did this:

`ini_set('track_errors', 1);

$fh = fopen($filename, 'r', false, $context);

if ( !$fh ) {

  echo 'fopen failed. reason: ', $php_errormsg;

}`


And I get this message: failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: I removed the "ftp://" from the link of the ftp host and now I'm able to connect. 
Thanks for you help Álvaro González!